# Rails object lifecycle - cross-transaction objects creation and destroy

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, http, lifecycle, object-lifetime

Is there a way to have objects on a Rails app that conserve their state between HTTP transactions?

For example, can I initialize a `Net::LDAP` connection somewhere and use it to retrieve data only restarting it on lost connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use class variables.

```
class Connection
  def initialize
    @@connection ||= # Start connectio
  end
end
```